# Mathematical Biology Question on Two Systems.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, biology

> Species x(t) and y(t) population models are as follows:
>
> ẋ = βx(1 - x/κ) - αxy
>
> ẏ = γxy - δy
>
> (Assuming α,β,γ,κ > 0)
>
> 1.) How do the populations behave in the absence of each other?
>
> 2.) What type of interaction does the coupling term describe and why?

How do I work out how the populations behave in the absence in each other for q1? Okay so from Benjamin Wang's help I do y=0 which gives me         ẋ = βx(1-x/κ) which means the population of x decreases exponentially in the absence of y as (1-x) is going to be negative as x>1. And then in the absence of x where x=0, ẏ= - δy so the population of y decreases exponentially too. So since the population of x and y decreases exponentially in the absence of each other I can say it is co-operation interaction? Is this right?

> 3.) How would I then calculate all the fixed points and the linear stability of them for this question too?

For 3.) the fixed points I got were (0,0) and (k,0), but are there any more. And how would I calculate the linear stability of these points?

Any help/hints would be much appreciated. Is there any reason why this question isn't being answered

Comment: For part 1, solve the system assuming y=0 constantly, and then solve the system again assuming x=0 constantly.

Comment: To find how does x behave in the absence of y, set y=0 constantly (identically). This means that y=0 for all t, which means that the derivative of y is also 0 constantly. Do this first.

Comment: For y=0, there is a fixed point (derivative equals zero) of x at x=k. Do you know what is a phase portrait and can you try to draw it?

Comment: For x = 0, you should say that y increases exponentially, not linearly. You should edit your question so that more people answer

Comment: My apologies. I meant “decrease exponentially”. Also, the fixed points seem correct.

Comment: Are there any more fixed points apart from (0,0) and (k,0)? I tried working another one out where I divide the ẋ equation by x throughout and the ẏ equation by y throughout and then treating them like simultaneous equations but I can't find another fixed point. How do I find whether (0,0) and (k,0) are stable or not?